# How to access button's id in android 1.5?

Tags: android

Mostly i am working on android 1.6. 
I made an application on 1.5 platform but i could not access button through like R.id.button1 like platform 1.6. Is there any idea?

Comment: Hm. Works for me. Got any code? Sure that you're using the right View to call findViewById on?

Comment: You need to much more detail with your questions, like source code and error messages and stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure .R file has been auto generated? 
   If not, do a Project->Clean->Rebuild in Eclipse and see if it changes anything.
2. Have you imported the correct Resource file? 
   Sometimes people import `android.R` and so cannot see their Ids.

Answer (score 0):

Import

```
import com.your.package.R;
```

Comment: I imported all required package like in android 1.6 platform, but in 1.5 platform it shows error.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. If you need to import your own package.R then you've broken something and this isn't the right way to fix it.